# Cloud Firestore: on realtime listeners, charged a read even if no changes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I would like some explanation about the pricing for the realtime listener.

On the Firestore documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing) it's stated:

> if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for example,
>   if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as if you had
>   issued a brand-new query.

What about if there are no changes (neither locally, nor remotely). Do you still get charged for a read when you reconnect after 30 minutes?

In such case it seems a pricing burden comparing to the Firebase Realtime Database, where if you enable the offline caching, the listeners don't download any new data and hence you are not charged.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47898317/if-persistence-is-enabled-what-counts-as-read-operations-when-data-exists-in-ca?rq=1), you don't get charged for reads that are fulfilled by the local cache.

However you would still get charged for 1 read for the query itself (regardless of the results).

Comment: Please comment if you're going to downvote so the convo on SO stays productive.  Thanks!